# MS Graph [V1.0]: $orderBy completely ignores the $skip param

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

According to the [doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters), you should be able to use $top,$skip and $orderBy at the same time.

$top & $skip works as expected, but as soon as you add $orderBy it's ignoring the $skip constraint.

you can reproduce the examples below in the [graph explorer:](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#)

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$select=id,subject&$orderBy=lastModifiedDateTime%20asc&$top=1&$skip=0

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$select=id,subject&$orderBy=lastModifiedDateTime%20asc&$top=1&$skip=1

Answer (score 1):

Your query string is wrong. You miss the $ before skip. The right query string resembles the following:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$select=id,subject,bodyPreview&$orderBy=lastModifiedDateTime asc&$top=1&$skip=6
```

**Note**:
Use some real data to test(no matter real business data or the data from O365 trail account), the API will work well. Not sure why the default mock data doesn't work, maybe PG limit some mock data query. So mock test data only for reference, developer need to create own data source.

Comment: thanks - that was a typo, but doesn't solve the issue :)

Comment: The right query string works well on my side. Do you use a real signed-in user or jsut the mock data? My test based on the real data, so the query string is OK. There are must be some other wrong config or such on your side.

Comment: hmm that's weird - I do test with a real signed-in user. Are you saying that querying with different $skip returns different results? It does return identical result when query with different $skip values...

Comment: Yes, the $skip works well on my side. Just use your query string and change the value of $Skip. I have tried xx@XX.onmicrosoft, XX@hotmail.com and xx@enterprisedomine.com, all of them works well.